# Update ng-click value after the click - angular JS

Tags: angularjs

Suppose that we have a function call for a ng-click and after that function class, if suppose the another function is to be called for - How will this scenario be achieved??

For eg:

the function1() should change ng-click's value to function2()

Can anyone please solve this scenario?

Comment: If you really need different functionality on different clicks you could keep a track of the click count from one function and trigger the functions you're interested in from there.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<button ng-click="aFunction()">Click Me</button>
```

Controller code:

```
angular.module('yourModule').controller(function($scope){

  function function1(){
    //whatever you want the first function to do;
    $scope.myFunction = function2;
  };

  function function2(){
  };

  $scope.myFunction = function1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change function variables like usual ones:

```
<button ng-click="do()">Do</button>

$scope.do = function(functionName) {
  console.log(1);
  $scope.do = $scope.other;
};

$scope.other = function() {
  console.log(2);
};
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/41clFC1MlYygljPhLRHB?p=preview